# Highlight words inside existing PDF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I need to highlight a set of words inside an existing PDF given specific coordinates that i have already extracted.
I am working with pdfbox by Apache (last version 2.0.8).
There is an example file I can use to such a purpose (AddAnnotations.java inside the pdfbox website) but I think this example was compiled with an older Java version as the following import does not work:

`import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationHighlight;`

Can anyone help me with that? Which is the simplest way to highlight words by using this library?

Comment: That is the development trunk. Take the file from the source code download.

Comment: Or from https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/AddAnnotations.java?view=markup

Comment: Thanks @TilmanHausherr

Comment: Assuming you got it to work: consider deleting your question or answer it yourself so that there are no orphans (don't just post the link, copy the relevant code from it or post your own code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the code to highlight ALL the words inside a PDF document. Highlighting only a specific set of words can be easily performed modifying this script. Please note this is only a test and further checks are needed for words that terminates in a new line as well as words placed in negative landscape/portrait PDF pages. Optimizing this script is also possible.

This script was built using Apache PDFBox 2.0.8.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.TextPosition;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotation;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationTextMarkup;

public class TestAnnotatePDF extends PDFTextStripper
{
    static List<double[]> coordinates;
    static ArrayList tokenStream;

    public TestAnnotatePDF() throws IOException
    {
        //data structed containing coordinates information for each token
        coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

        //List of words extracted from text (considering a whitespace-based tokenization)
        tokenStream = new ArrayList();
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {

        try
        {   
           //Loading an existing document
           File file = new File("MyDocument");
           PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

           //extended PDFTextStripper class
           PDFTextStripper stripper = new TestAnnotatePDF();

           //Get number of pages
           int number_of_pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().getCount();

           //The method writeText will invoke an override version of writeString
           Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
           stripper.writeText(document, dummy);

           //Print collected information
           System.out.println(tokenStream);
           System.out.println(tokenStream.size());
           System.out.println(coordinates.size());

           double page_height;
           double page_width;
           double width, height, minx, maxx, miny, maxy;
           int rotation;

           //scan each page and highlitht all the words inside them
           for (int page_index = 0; page_index < number_of_pages; page_index++)
           {   
               //get current page
               PDPage page = document.getPage(page_index);

               //Get annotations for the selected page
               List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();

               //Define a color to use for highlighting text
               PDColor red = new PDColor(new float[] { 1, 0, 0 }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);

               //Page height and width
               page_height = page.getMediaBox().getHeight();
               page_width  = page.getMediaBox().getWidth();

               //Scan collected coordinates
               for (int i=0; i<coordinates.size(); i++)
                  {
                   //if the current coordinates are not related to the current
                   //page, ignore them
                   if ((int) coordinates.get(i)[4] != (page_index+1))
                      continue;
                   else
                   {
                       //get rotation of the page...portrait..landscape..
                       rotation = (int) coordinates.get(i)[7];

                       //page rotated of 90degrees
                       if (rotation == 90)
                       {
                           height = coordinates.get(i)[5];
                           width = coordinates.get(i)[6];
                           width = (page_height * width)/page_width;

                           //define coordinates of a rectangle
                           maxx = coordinates.get(i)[1];
                           minx = coordinates.get(i)[1] - height;
                           miny = coordinates.get(i)[0];
                           maxy = coordinates.get(i)[0] + width;
                       }
                       else //i should add here the cases -90/-180 degrees
                       {
                           height = coordinates.get(i)[5];
                           minx = coordinates.get(i)[0];
                           maxx = coordinates.get(i)[2];
                           miny = page_height - coordinates.get(i)[1];
                           maxy = page_height - coordinates.get(i)[3] + height;
                       }

                       //Add an annotation for each scanned word
                       PDAnnotationTextMarkup txtMark = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT);
                       txtMark.setColor(red);
                       txtMark.setConstantOpacity((float)0.3); // 30% transparent
                       PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
                       position.setLowerLeftX((float) minx);
                       position.setLowerLeftY((float) miny);
                       position.setUpperRightX((float) maxx);
                       position.setUpperRightY((float) ((float) maxy+height));
                       txtMark.setRectangle(position);

                       float[] quads = new float[8];
                       quads[0] = position.getLowerLeftX();  // x1
                       quads[1] = position.getUpperRightY()-2; // y1
                       quads[2] = position.getUpperRightX(); // x2
                       quads[3] = quads[1]; // y2
                       quads[4] = quads[0];  // x3
                       quads[5] = position.getLowerLeftY()-2; // y3
                       quads[6] = quads[2]; // x4
                       quads[7] = quads[5]; // y5
                       txtMark.setQuadPoints(quads);
                       txtMark.setContents(tokenStream.get(i).toString());
                       annotations.add(txtMark);
                   }    
               }
           }

           //Saving the document in a new file
           File highlighted_doc = new File("MyDocument_final.pdf");
           document.save(highlighted_doc);

        document.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

@Override
protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
{ 
    String token = "";
    int token_length = textPositions.size();
    int counter = 1;
    double minx = 0,maxx = 0,miny = 0,maxy =0; 
    double height = 0;
    double width = 0;
    int rotation = 0;

    for (TextPosition text : textPositions)
    {          
        rotation = text.getRotation();

        if (text.getHeight() > height)
            height = text.getHeight(); 

        if (text.getWidth() > width)
            width = text.getWidth();

        //if it is the first char of the current word
        if (counter == 1)
        {
            minx = text.getX();
            miny = text.getY();
        }

        //if it is the last char of the current word
        if (counter == token_length)
        {
            maxx = text.getEndX();
            maxy = text.getY();
        }

        token += text;
        counter += 1;

    }

    tokenStream.add(token);
    double word_coordinates [] = {minx,miny,maxx,maxy,this.getCurrentPageNo(), height, width, rotation};
    coordinates.add(word_coordinates);
}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code to highlight specific words inside a PDF document. Please note this is working for highlighting the line of the search text. **Highlight specific words in a PDF is still in progress...** Any suggestion to highlight specific words on top of this code will be highly appreciated.

This script was built using Apache PDFBox 2.0.8

```java
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.io.Writer;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotation;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationTextMarkup;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.text.TextPosition;

    public class PDFhighlightDemo extends PDFTextStripper {

        public PDFhighlightDemo()  throws IOException {
            super();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {
            PDDocument document = null;
            String fileName = "Demo1.pdf";
            try {
                document = PDDocument.load( new File(fileName) );
                PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFhighlightDemo();
                stripper.setSortByPosition( true );

                stripper.setStartPage( 0 );
                stripper.setEndPage( document.getNumberOfPages() );

                Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
                stripper.writeText(document, dummy);

                File file1 = new File("FinalPDF.pdf");
                document.save(file1);
            }
            finally {
                if( document != null ) {
                    document.close();
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Override the default functionality of PDFTextStripper.writeString()
         */

        @Override
        protected void writeString(String string, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
            boolean isFound = false;

            float posXInit1  = 0, 
                    posXEnd1   = 0, 
                    posYInit1  = 0,
                    posYEnd1   = 0,
                    width1     = 0, 
                    height1    = 0, 
                    fontHeight1 = 0;

            String[] criteria = {"angular", "prepared"};

            for (int i = 0; i < criteria.length; i++) {
                if (string.contains(criteria[i])) {
                    isFound = true;
                } 
            }
            if (isFound) {

                for(TextPosition textPosition:textPositions) {

                  posXInit1 = textPositions.get(0).getXDirAdj(); 
                  posXEnd1  = textPositions.get(textPositions.size() - 1).getXDirAdj() + textPositions.get(textPositions.size() - 1).getWidth();
                  posYInit1 = textPositions.get(0).getPageHeight() - textPositions.get(0).getYDirAdj();
                  posYEnd1  = textPositions.get(0).getPageHeight() - textPositions.get(textPositions.size() - 1).getYDirAdj();
                  width1    = textPositions.get(0).getWidthDirAdj();
                  height1   = textPositions.get(0).getHeightDir();

                }


                float quadPoints[] = {posXInit1, posYEnd1 + height1 + 2, posXEnd1, posYEnd1 + height1 + 2, posXInit1, posYInit1 - 2, posXEnd1, posYEnd1 - 2};

                List<PDAnnotation> annotations = document.getPage(this.getCurrentPageNo() - 1).getAnnotations();
                PDAnnotationTextMarkup highlight = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_HIGHLIGHT);

                PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
                position.setLowerLeftX(posXInit1);
                position.setLowerLeftY(posYEnd1);
                position.setUpperRightX(posXEnd1);
                position.setUpperRightY(posYEnd1 + height1);

                highlight.setRectangle(position);

                // quadPoints is array of x,y coordinates in Z-like order (top-left, top-right, bottom-left,bottom-right) 
                // of the area to be highlighted

                highlight.setQuadPoints(quadPoints);

                PDColor yellow = new PDColor(new float[]{1, 1, 1 / 255F}, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE);
                highlight.setColor(yellow);
                annotations.add(highlight);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Highlight specific words in a document using PDFclown.

```
package com.NLP.demo;

import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.pdfclown.documents.Page;
import org.pdfclown.documents.contents.ITextString;
import org.pdfclown.documents.contents.TextChar;
import org.pdfclown.documents.interaction.annotations.TextMarkup;
import org.pdfclown.documents.interaction.annotations.TextMarkup.MarkupTypeEnum;
import org.pdfclown.files.SerializationModeEnum;
import org.pdfclown.tools.TextExtractor;
import org.pdfclown.util.math.Interval;
import org.pdfclown.util.math.geom.Quad;

public class PDFCrownDemo  {

    public static void main() throws IOException {
        PDFCrownDemo PDFCrownDemo=new PDFCrownDemo();
        PDFCrownDemo.highlighttext();

    }

    public void highlighttext() throws IOException{

        org.pdfclown.files.File file = new org.pdfclown.files.File("src/main/resources/XXX.pdf");   
        String textRegEx = "Contract";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(textRegEx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        TextExtractor textExtractor = new TextExtractor(true, true);

        for(final Page page : file.getDocument().getPages())
        {
          Map<Rectangle2D,List<ITextString>> textStrings = textExtractor.extract(page);
          final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(TextExtractor.toString(textStrings));
         textExtractor.filter(textStrings,new TextExtractor.IIntervalFilter()
            {
              @Override
              public boolean hasNext()
              {return matcher.find();}

              @Override
              public Interval next()
              {return new Interval(matcher.start(), matcher.end());}

              @Override
              public void process(Interval interval,ITextString match)
              {
                // Defining the highlight box of the text pattern match...
                List highlightQuads = new ArrayList();
                {
                  /*
                    NOTE: A text pattern match may be split across multiple contiguous lines,
                    so we have to define a distinct highlight box for each text chunk.
                  */
                  Rectangle2D textBox = null;
                  for(TextChar textChar : match.getTextChars())
                  {
                    Rectangle2D textCharBox = textChar.getBox();
                    if(textBox == null)
                    {textBox = (Rectangle2D)textCharBox.clone();}
                    else
                    {
                      if(textCharBox.getY() > textBox.getMaxY())
                      {
                        highlightQuads.add(Quad.get(textBox));
                        textBox = (Rectangle2D)textCharBox.clone();
                      }
                      else
                      {textBox.add(textCharBox);}
                    }
                  }
                  highlightQuads.add(Quad.get(textBox));
                }
                // Highlight the text pattern match!
                new TextMarkup(page,MarkupTypeEnum.Highlight, highlightQuads);
              }

              @Override
              public void remove(
                )
              {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
            }
            );
        }

        //file.save(SerializationModeEnum.Incremental);
        file.save(new java.io.File("src/main/resources/XXX.pdf"), SerializationModeEnum.Standard);
    }

}
```