# java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class java.awt.Point that attempts to sub-type erroneous class java.awt.geom.Point2D : Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf-generation, pdfbox

i implement this Code snippet
[script was built using Apache PDFBox 2.0.8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60388918/14653921)

My Gradle is

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pakigname"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "app/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
```

and   `implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.8'`

But When i Run Code then Crash Occurs in the code at `document = PDDocument.load( new File(fileName) );`.
My Logcat is

```
    2021-08-26 11:39:10.179 1834-14006/? E/HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 103
2021-08-26 11:39:10.332 14038-14038/com.pakigname
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pakigname, PID: 14038
    java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class java.awt.Point that attempts to sub-type erroneous class java.awt.geom.Point2D (declaration of 'java.awt.Point' appears in /data/app/com.pakigname-uS435DQf_FvtwKZ2f0zE3w==/base.apk:classes3.dex)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.<clinit>(PDDocument.java:104)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:917)
        at com.pakigname.extractandhiglightText.PDFhighlightDemo.main(PDFhighlightDemo.java:29)
        at com.pakigname.PdfViewerActivity.onCreate(PdfViewerActivity.java:289)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class java.awt.geom.Point2D: void java.awt.geom.Point2D.<init>() failed to verify: void java.awt.geom.Point2D.<init>(): [0x0] Constructor returning without calling superclass constructor (declaration of 'java.awt.geom.Point2D' appears in /data/app/com.pakigname-uS435DQf_FvtwKZ2f0zE3w==/base.apk:classes3.dex)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.<clinit>(PDDocument.java:104) 
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:917) 
        at com.pakigname.extractandhiglightText.PDFhighlightDemo.main(PDFhighlightDemo.java:29) 
        at com.pakigname.PdfViewerActivity.onCreate(PdfViewerActivity.java:289) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
2021-08-26 11:39:10.332 781-2400/? E/iMonitor: FaultDetect: DUMPTOOL_PRINTF return.
```

and if i move to PDFBox 3.0.0-RC1 (Latest Version) Then in the example Code snippet `posYInit1 = textPositions.get(0).getPageHeight() - textPositions.get(0).getYDirAdj();`
getPageHeight() give the Eror.

This Error is Occur when i am using
[java-rt-jar-stubs](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavartjarstubs150jar.htm)

and when i remove this [java-rt-jar-stubs](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavartjarstubs150jar.htm) from project Flowwing Crash occur. then Error is **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Point;** and my logcat is

```
 Process: com.pakigname, PID: 15624
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Point;
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.<clinit>(PDDocument.java:104)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:917)
        at com.pakigname.extractandhiglightText.TestAnnotatePDF.main(TestAnnotatePDF.java:40)
        at com.pakigname.PdfViewerActivity.onCreate(PdfViewerActivity.java:289)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.Point" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.pakigname-3wA3j8RkT6oHi12HlUHLmw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.pakigname-3wA3j8RkT6oHi12HlUHLmw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.pakigname-3wA3j8RkT6oHi12HlUHLmw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
```

Comment: Most of Apache PDFBox doesn't work with Android. You need PDFBox for Android. https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/